# Only dispose of initialized objects?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I have an API wrapper that has a series of properties that are initialized on their first use. When the class's `Disposed` method is called, it disposes of all of the other classes it's storing. However, there is a good chance only one or two of these other classes have been initialized anyways. If these classes aren't already initialized, the `Dispose` method actually ends up initializing them and them disposing them. This is massively resource and time intensive, but I cannot think of a method to remedy it.

Here's the class.

```
public class SalesForceApi : ISalesForce, IDisposable
{
    public Logger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    private IAccounts _accounts;
    private IAttachments _attachments;
    private ICases _cases;
    private IContacts _contacts;
    private IGroups _groups;
    private IRecordTypes _recordTypes;
    private IUsers _users;

    public IAccounts Accounts => _accounts ?? (_accounts = new Accounts());

    public IAttachments Attachments => _attachments ?? (_attachments = new Attachments());
    public ICases Cases => _cases ?? (_cases = new Cases());
    public IContacts Contacts => _contacts ?? (_contacts = new Contacts());
    public IGroups Groups => _groups ?? (_groups = new Groups());
    public IRecordTypes RecordTypes => _recordTypes ?? (_recordTypes = new RecordTypes());
    public IUsers Users => _users ?? (_users = new Users());

    public SalesForceApi()
    {

    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Acccounts...");
        Accounts.Dispose();
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Attachments...");
        Attachments.Dispose();
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Cases...");
        Cases.Dispose();
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Contacts...");
        Contacts.Dispose();
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Groups...");
        Groups.Dispose();
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of RecordTypes...");
        RecordTypes.Dispose();
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Users...");
        Users.Dispose();
    }
}
```

And here is what the resulting log looks like:

```
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of Acccounts...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging into SalesForce...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::SalesForce login successful!
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of Attachments...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging into SalesForce...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::SalesForce login successful!
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of Cases...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging into SalesForce...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::SalesForce login successful!
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of Contacts...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of Groups...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging into SalesForce...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::SalesForce login successful!
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of RecordTypes...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging into SalesForce...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::SalesForce login successful!
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
SalesForceApi_v1.SalesForceApi::Disposing of Users...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging into SalesForce...
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::SalesForce login successful!
SalesForceApi_v1.Requests.RequestBase::Logging out of SalesForce.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When disposing, don't call the methods that lazy-init; test and dispose the private member variables (_accounts, etc.).

Comment: Ouch, I've been refactoring and just noticed I wasn't disposing the the private members.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use properties in the `Dispose` method, use private fields.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Logger.Trace("Disposing of Acccounts...");
    if(_accounts != null) _accounts.Dispose();
    Logger.Trace("Disposing of Attachments...");
    if(_attachments != null) _attachments.Dispose();
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your disposal in a private member null check. Since you are lazy loading, calling `Property.Dispose()` actually creates an instance of the class, just to dispose of it. I also like to set my members to null after disposal so that it does throw a NullReferenceException if I try to access it again.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_accounts != null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Acccounts...");
        Accounts.Dispose();
        // or
        // _accounts.Dispose();
        // _accounts = null;
    }
    if (_attachments != null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Attachments...");
        Attachments.Dispose();
        // or
        // _attachments.Dispose();
        // _attachments = null;
    }
    if (_cases != null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Cases...");
        Cases.Dispose();
        // or
        // _cases.Dispose();
        // _cases= null;
    }
    if (_contacts != null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Contacts...");
        Contacts.Dispose();
        // or
        // _contacts.Dispose();
        // _contacts = null;
    }
    if (_groups != null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Groups...");
        Groups.Dispose();
        // or
        // _groups.Dispose();
        // _groups = null;
    }
    if (_recordTypes != null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of RecordTypes...");
        RecordTypes.Dispose();
        // or
        // _recordTypes.Dispose();
        // _recordTypes = null;
    }
    if (_users!= null) 
    {
        Logger.Trace("Disposing of Users...");
        Users.Dispose();
        // or
        // _users.Dispose();
        // _users= null;
    }
}
```